# Which permissions are required to enable History Tracking?

Tags: permissions, history-tracking

Working through some training exercises and trying to track history on some fields in the Account object.

I'm getting an Insufficient Privileges error.  Which permission do I need to be able to do this?

[image: Setup->Object Manager->Account>Fields & Relationships]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Customize Application` permission to be able to set field history tracking.

Source: [Track Field History for Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Jayant.  Also it seems that with permission sets, you need to clone an existing one , rather than edit an old one.  For this I also need to get into Object permissions and allow editing on the object and fields.

Comment: Typically a system administrator profile will have all these necessary permissions as all these activities are part of an admin's job.